# How to apply watch using array in Vuejs between parents and child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I made parent component like below.

```
// parent component

<template>
   <layout
    v-for="(value, idx) in array"
    :pickUpLength="array.length"
    :idx="idx"
    :key="idx"
   >
   <button @click="addArray">add</add>
</template>

data(){
  array:[
     {"date" : "", "time": ""},
     {"date" : "", "time": ""}
  ]
}
methods:{
  addArray(){
     this.array.splice(this.array.length - 1, 0, {"yes":"no"})
  }
```

And there is a child component.

```
<template>

</template>

props:["pickUpLength"],
watch:{
    pickUpLength:{
      handler(){
          console.log(idx)
      }
   }
}
```

When I click addArray button in parent component, pickUpLength of child component is changed as well.
Therefore, watch works. But the thing is console.log(idx) gives only "0, 1". But In this case the total idx is '3' instead of 2.

So I expect "0,1,2".
I don't know which the problem is.
Could you recommend some solution? And thank you so much for reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<template>
   <layout
    v-for="(value, idx) in array"
    :pickUpLength="array.length"
    :idx="idx"
    :key="idx"
   >
   <button @click="addArray">add</add>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    array:[
      {"date" : "", "time": ""},
      {"date" : "", "time": ""}
    ]
  },
  methods:{
    addArray(newVal){
      // This is what you are doing. You can't "watch" arrays or Objects in Vue.js v2.x.x (changing in v3.x.x).
      // this.array.splice(this.array.length - 1, 0, {"yes":"no"})
      
      // This is what you have to do in this situation (based upon your comments from my original answer):
      this.array = this.array.slice(0, this.array.length - 1).concat(newVal, this.array[this.array.length - 1]);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. but I want to put in the middle of array not the end position. Could you recommend the other solution?

Comment: How are you going to be determining where in the array that you will be placing the item? Will it be an index? Will it be based on a value that already exists in the array? More information will be helpful so that I can give you a correct answer.

Comment: I want to put a new object ('6')  like this. [1,2,3,4] => [1,2,3,6,4]. And again, with 9, [1,2,3,6,4] => [1,2,3,6,9,4]. That is the new object always is put before the last object. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @DDDD => I updated my answer with a piece of code that should work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I have a question. Why it doesn't catch by watch, when new object put inside of an array? That is, when I use watch 'array.length' inside child component, the value of length 3. It's correct. But inside of watch , idx gives only '0, 1'. I guess the watch doesn't catch the last object pushed by new object. Is it correct what I said? and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: @DDDD => You're logging two different values in the watcher. You need to change the "console.log(idx)" to "console.log(val)" where "val" is the parameter for the handler function (like "handler(val)").